# Screen-reader reading out Line Numbers in Java JTextArea

Tags: java, accessibility, screen-readers, voiceover, jaws-screen-reader

I'm helping create an accessible IDE in java and was wondering how can I get programs like **Voice Over** and **JAWS** (both screen-readers for the visually impaired, using `getAccessibleContent` to receive information) to read out what number line they're on when they move to a new line in a `JTextArea`?

Comment: Access Bridge might help. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136191.html Is the IDE you're making exclusive only for blind users?

Comment: It is not exclusive to blind users but must be made accessible to them as well as visually impaired users and users who see with no visual impairment. I have seen come across Access Bridge, however I'm developing on a mac (I have a Windows machine I can test my repo with), and the examples and demos with Access Bridge all seem to be oriented for Windows users... So I'm unsure if it's been working or not.